# Hotspot on video

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a hotspot in a `<video>` HTML 5 tag. I know that it's possible to do it in `<img>` elements. For some reason, it's not working for videos.

Here I have an example of my code:

```
<video ng-src="/some-path" type='video/mp4' autoplay loop usemap="#myArea" />
<map name="myArea">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 768, 1024" ng-click="onTouch()">
</map>
```

Do you know if it's possible?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my approach and solved the problem using this:

1. I've add a div in my code, with my onTouch() event:

   `<div class="overlay" ng-click="onTouch()" />`
2. I used the follow CSS for the "overlay"class:

   `.overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 900px;
    height: 90px;
    left: 30px; 
    color: #FFF; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 305px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    z-index: 2147483647;
   }`

Comment: That is also how I solved it, but it would be nice if there was some way to use actual hotspots, as divs can behave differently across browsers and devices.