# How to make hotspots on video for web

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I see there is already a question abour [Hotspot on video](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28616912/3835843). I can't solve my problem 
by this answer. I want to show some tooltip on video at different time frame. Like this image :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 video: possible to place regular html content over video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626700/html5-video-possible-to-place-regular-html-content-over-video)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using HTML5 video control and JavaScript. You have to grab your time frame at the `timeupdate` event using JavaScript, then you need to show your tooltip on that time.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="video_box">
    <div id="caption"></div>
    <div id="hotspot"></div>
    <div>
        <video id='sampleVideo' controls>
            <source id='mp4' src="your-video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            <p>HTML5 Video is not supported by this browser.</p>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(window).bind('load', init);
    })($);
</script>
```

**JavaScript(scripts.js) :**

```
// Currently shown hotspot.
    var idxHotspot = -1;

// Set up our hotspots.
var arrHotspots = [
    {"startTime":1,"endTime":20,"top":100,"left":100,"text":"I will be visible during 1 to 20 second"},
    {"startTime":21,"endTime":40,"top":150,"left":200,"text":"I will be visible during 21 to 40 second"},
    {"startTime":41,"endTime":60,"top":200,"left":300,"text":"I will be visible during 41 to 60 second"}
];

function init() {

    var video = $('#sampleVideo')[0];
    var $hotspot = $('#hotspot');
    var $caption = $('#caption');

    // Add the mouse events for the hotspot
    $hotspot.bind('mouseover', function(event) {
        video.pause();
    });

    $hotspot.bind('mouseout', function() {
        video.play();
    });

    // Determine when to show a hotspot.
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {

        // Grab the current video pointer time mark.
        var vidCurrentTime = video.currentTime;

        // Set flag if we need to show a new hotspot.
        var idxNewHotspot = -1;

        // Find if need to show a hostpot. Assumes only one hotspot at a time.
        for (var i=0; i<arrHotspots.length; i++) {
            if (vidCurrentTime >= arrHotspots[i].startTime && vidCurrentTime < arrHotspots[i].endTime) {
                idxNewHotspot = i;
            }
        }

        // Set up hotspot or remove a currently displayed one.
        if (idxNewHotspot > -1) {
            if (idxNewHotspot != idxHotspot) {

                // Position and size hotspot.
                $hotspot.css({
                    left : arrHotspots[idxNewHotspot].left+'px',
                    top : arrHotspots[idxNewHotspot].top+'px'
                }).show();

                // Position and size Caption.
                $caption.html(arrHotspots[idxNewHotspot].text);
                $caption.css({
                    left: (arrHotspots[idxNewHotspot].left + 20) + "px",
                    top: (arrHotspots[idxNewHotspot].top - 75) + "px"
                }).show();

                // Set the current hotspot shown.
                idxHotspot = idxNewHotspot;
            }
        } else {
            // Hide the current hotspot
            $hotspot.hide();
            $caption.hide();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Recently i made a video hotspot you can check it. [Hotspot Video](https://github.com/arif2009/HotspotVideo.git).
I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks your git project helps me lot...